# Variable isn't changing in for loop - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, variables, for-loop, scope

Why is this outputting each feedName as the same name (MedryBW)? I've spent a while messing around with it, can't figure it out. I want it to output the name of the feed in each iteration of the loop rather than repeating the same one over and over again. Thanks everyone.

```
var feeds = ["Towellie", "TrumpSC", "TeamSp00ky", "TwitchPlaysPokemon", "Widgitybear", "AriaBlarg", "TheMexicanRunner", "OPNerd", "rabbitbong", "Wingsofdeath", "MedryBW"];

$(document).ready(function(){
    for(x = 0; x < feeds.length; x++){
        var feedName = feeds[x];
        $.getJSON('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/' + feeds[x] + '?callback=?', function(data) {
            if(data.stream === null){
                $('#feeds').append("<p>" + feedName + " is offline </p>");
            } else {
                $('#feeds').append("<p>" + feedName + " is streaming "  (data.stream.game) + "/<p>");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have written Ajax in for loop , The success callback executes after for loop has executed

```
var feeds = ["Towellie", "TrumpSC", "TeamSp00ky", "TwitchPlaysPokemon", "Widgitybear", "AriaBlarg", "TheMexicanRunner", "OPNerd", "rabbitbong", "Wingsofdeath", "MedryBW"];

$(document).ready(function() {
  feeds.forEach(function(feedName) {
    $.getJSON('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/' + feedName + '?callback=?', function(data) {
      if (data.stream === null) {
        $('#feeds').append("<p>" + feedName + " is offline </p>");
      } else {
        $('#feeds').append("<p>" + feedName + " is streaming " + (data.stream.game) + "/<p>");
      }
    });

  });
})
```

THe Above change will work

Answer (score 3):

Because callback function runs much later, not in the loop, and it just gets variable value after loop has finished (last value), use `bind` function to pass variable to the function

```
var feeds = ["Towellie", "TrumpSC", "TeamSp00ky", "TwitchPlaysPokemon", "Widgitybear", "AriaBlarg", "TheMexicanRunner", "OPNerd", "rabbitbong", "Wingsofdeath", "MedryBW"];

$(document).ready(function() {
    for(x = 0; x < feeds.length; x++){
        var feedName = feeds[x];
        $.getJSON('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/' + feeds[x] + '?callback=?', function(feedName, data) {
            if (data.stream === null) {
                $('#feeds').append("<p>" + feedName + " is offline </p>");
            }else{
                $('#feeds').append("<p>" + feedName + " is streaming " + (data.stream.game) + "/<p>");
            }
        }.bind(this, feedName));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by.

```
var feeds = ["Towellie", "TrumpSC", "TeamSp00ky", "TwitchPlaysPokemon", "Widgitybear", "AriaBlarg", "TheMexicanRunner", "OPNerd", "rabbitbong", "Wingsofdeath", "MedryBW"];

        $(document).ready(function(){
        var divText;
        for(x = 0; x < feeds.length; x++){
            var feedName = feeds[x];
            $.getJSON('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/' + feeds[x] + '?callback=?', function(data) {
          if(data.stream === null){
         divText = divText + '<p>'+feedName+' is offline </p>';
          }else{
         divText = divText + '<p>'+feedName+' is streaming '+(data.stream.game) +'</p>'
        }
        });
        }
     $('#feeds').append(divText); 
     //or $('#feeds').html(divText); 

        })
```